# Sharepoint O365 calendar items appear on same line in month view

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, security-testing-o365

I have this weird issue
In monthly calendar view some items appear on the same line instead of underneath each other
This does not happen in day or week view
see the screen shot below
[image]